# Why I can't set the value

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is wrong with this statement, it works when I dont set the @label

```
Declare
     @SourceTable varchar(255) = '[ServerXX\XX].[database].[dbo].[Manager]',
     @Label varchar(255)

     SET @Label = (SELECT Manager 
                FROM (
                    SELECT Manager, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ManagerID) AS RowNum
                    FROM @SourceTable
                     ) AS MyDerivedTable 
                WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum = 2);

                print @Label
```

Error: but when I change @SourceTable with [ServerXX\XX].[database].[dbo].[Manager]...... it works but I want to use my @SourceTable

```
Must declare the table variable "@SourceTable".
```

Comment: What errors are being returned? Does the `SELECT` query return multiple values when you call it without setting `@Label`?

Comment: First, this is tagged Oracle but appears to be SQL Server code.  Define "works when I don't set the @label".  Since assigning a value to @label seems to be the entire point of the block, I can't figure out what that means.  Although I can guess, if you're getting an error, include the error.

Comment: `DECLARE` both variables instead of combining? Syntax just looks funky to me. Could easily be wrong though, as I'm not 100% sure of all the SQL shorthand options.

Comment: Assuming that you are really using SQL Server, if your goal is to dynamically assemble and execute a SQL statement, you'd need to use sp_executesql https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Does the SQL return 1 value when you run it separately?